# matching different types of resolution to my program

Tags: android

i have this code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="66dp" android:gravity="center"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="120px"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="hight"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/up"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
             />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="120px"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="low "
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/down"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
             />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="120px"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="refresh"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/refresh"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
             />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGraf"
            android:layout_width="120px"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="graf"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/graf2"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

when i run on 480 X 800 device it looks excellent

but if i run on 720 X 1280 device the buttons looks small and ugly.

**How can I make the buttons grow evenly and will take all the screen ?**

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html. http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Comment: THe short answer is *never* define the size of a UI element in `px` and even using `dp` will have varying results depending on if Android decides a device is ldpi, mdpi, hdpi etc. The links in the comment above are definitely worth looking at.

Comment: Hardcoding the sizes will always be a problem, its lame programming to hardcode. Instead you should use weights.

Answer (score 0):

Set their width to 0dp and use weights.  That will cause them to grow in accordance to their weight.

Comment: Also use 66dp for all your heights. There doesn't need to be a 1 dp difference with your LinearLayout, plus it's better if your button/image measurements are easily divisible by two.

Answer (score 0):

try to put the same drawables in drawable-hdpi folder drawable-mdpi drawable-xhdpi folders they will looks more better. and use the dip unit for the height an width attributes

Answer (score 0):

Place your images in drawable-xhdpi folder,  since Nexus phones always take images from these folder. Otherwise you have to design a seperate layout for them, like layout-normal-xhdpi.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some updated code that will scale the size of the buttons to use the available width if your layout.

Some notes first though:
- Please avoid using exact pixel sizes.  Notice that I have changed the height of each of the buttons to wrap_content.  If you require the buttons to be bigger, please use DP instead of PX.  This will ensure that the button sizes remain consistent across devices with different screen resolutions.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/up"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:text="hight"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/down"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:text="low "
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/refresh"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:text="refresh"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGraf"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/graf2"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:text="graf"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
```